# iOS Custom Slider remove min and max space from both ends

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I'm trying to make custom slider using

```
class MySlider: UISlider {

    override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        let customBounds = CGRect(origin: bounds.origin, size: CGSize(width: bounds.size.width, height: 5.0))
        super.trackRect(forBounds: customBounds)
        return customBounds
    }
}
```

Updated thumb/max/min tint colour from storyboard
[image]

The problem is need to remove min and max space from both ends as shown in pics. How i can do that?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this without subclassing:

Set **Thumb Tint:** `Default` through IB

```
@IBOutlet weak var slider: MySlider!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let size = CGSize(width: 1 , height: 1)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        let finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        slider.setThumbImage(finalImage, for: .normal)
    }
```

Comment: But if it goes beyond ends its not coming back, can't we make that return back

Comment: Also it's rounded cornors disspper on value 100